# Rails concurrency with unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, scalability, unicorn, fork

There is a lot of information on the subject and I've read a lot of it and because I am still confused I've decided to ask about it here.

What I dont understand is the following: imagine a single core server with only one rails action that takes 2 sec to complete ( because of the waiting for a database response for example ), I know that I need to avoid that by putting things in background and etc but just for the sake of learning..., anyhow, if there is only one unicorn worker, then two concurrent requests will take 4 seconds, but this situation can be solved by increasing the number of workers to 2, since the CPU is not busy while one request is waiting for the database response, and therefore these 2 concurrent requests will take around 2 seconds with 2 workers on only one core server, am I right about it? If I am not, please correct me and describe the way it is. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's more or less as you described.

Comment: I see, thank you. You may write it as an answer and I will accept it, if you wanna

Comment: One note, though: with just one unicorn worker, the requests will **not** be concurrent (which means "executing at the same time"). One will wait for another to finish (so they will be executed *serially*, not *concurrently*)

Comment: I see, I know that, I just meant that they were created at the same time, like two users sending a get request for some page... By the way, if one of the two workers is waiting for a database response, what is responsible for seeing it and handing another request over to the second worker, if you understand what I mean...

Comment: here's how unicorn distributes load: http://tomayko.com/writings/unicorn-is-unix